# Switching to nvidia graphics (nvidia prime,nvidia x server settings)

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to switch to my Nvidia graphic card via Nvidia x server settings, but it doesn't allow me. It shows the blocking sign. Any ideas?

--
with NVIDIA 745M

[image]

Comment: Your System may need to use the Bumblebee Project.  See this [Ubuntu Specific Wiki Entry](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Comment: Tried bumblebee before, but that is not what i'm aiming for. I would like to completely "disable" integrated graphics. Thanks for your response, but I need a different solution.

Comment: If you disable Integrated Graphics the only onboard display you'll have is the Intel Chipset.  It doesn't work the other way around.  See [this post that I quoted and helped write](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-972600-postdays-0-postorder-asc-start-25.html)

Comment: I didn't mean literaly, i've just wanted to force ubuntu to use nvidia by default. Anyway,thanks,I'll keep looking for solution.

Comment: "but it doesn't allow me" could you be more specific? How are you not allowed?

Comment: Ok,step by step: i click on "nvidia (performance mode)", it asks for a password, i enter the password and it just shows the block sign and return to previous state.

Comment: If you want, i can printscreen it?

Comment: The same issue I also have. Even when I have my external monitor connected the mouse pointer flickering. From my point of view Ubuntu 14.04 Alpha and Beta was more stable than the final release. Strange!

Comment: I think that your mouse flickering problem can be solved through settings. Go to system settings > displays, then select the unknown monitor and turn it off, maybe that will solve it. Also, i found out that a lot of people have the same issue with switching to Nvidia(performance mode). See this, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331-updates/+bug/1289876

Comment: This works greatly for my GEFORCE GT 425M.
Thanks a lot! Only thing now, I have found out how I could get my brightness control to work with this when using the gforce card. Its not working in the brightness menu window and also not with fn buttons. Hope somebody could advise me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solved my similar problem,

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

now I can switch using the prime-indicator applet

Comment: I followed the steps that you wrote,but I get the same thing. It's a bug that happened to a lot of people and i hope for a fix. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Worked for me! Something fishy happened. But, now works fine. 

Sometimes, when I switch graphics, Intel is ticked but when I click nvidia again, the error pops up. Is there any suggestion for that?

Comment: UPDATE: Some problem occurs when I switch between intel and nvidia. The options are missing in nvidia x server settings. Take a look at: http://s12.postimg.org/cuuhwytul/prob_1.jpg